# How to I use this library?

Tags: android

I want to use https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui library.

How do I use it?

Can I just go compile 'com.github.wasabeef.awesome-android-ui' or it is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a library but rather a list of libraries. Open the component you want to use ( eg.: dmytrodanylyk/android-process-button ) [https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/android-process-button] and see the instructions of how to use it.

Most of these are on Maven and/or gradle.

If you are using gradle, you can simply paste the following line of code in your **module gradle** ( NOT project gradle )

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply